# How to pull key name from array of objects in AngularFire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Can someone help me pull the unique object name from contents ($Id).  I'm able to loop over $scope.data in my template with ng-repeat but I can't get the name of that array.  Need this to build a URL reference.

In short, how do I get "2015-02-27T20:24:11-06:00"?  I can pull out item.count, item.handle, item.img_url, but {{item.$id}} doesn't work.

obj.$asArray();

[image: object of arrays]

obj.$asObject();

[image]

Comment: Seems like a great place to start here would be [the guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html). It will save you some thrashing with basic concepts like these.

Answer (score 1):

If you fetch the data `$asArray()` and save it on `$scope.data` you should simply be able to get the `$id` as you describe.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data">
  <p>id: {{item.$id}}</p>
</div>
```

However, I can't help but notice that your casing in `$Id` is wrong.

Comment: Tried your suggestion still didn't get the results (even with the casing change you pointed out).  Almost like it is not binding through to the template.

Comment: I find it strange that `item.handle` returns expected data while `item.$id` does not. Can you make a Plunker (or similar) that shows this issue ?

Comment: i agree.  i couldn't figure it out after a few days so that's why i broke down and posted here.

Comment: @billm you ever figure it out? I'm having the exact same issue. `item.value` prints my value but `item.$id` does not