# Reference a child by element

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I have the following div:

```
<div ng-repeat="state in Home.overlaySettings.data.games[0].events[0].states">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 noPadding" ng-repeat="feature in state.features" ng-show="state.name == Home.overlaySettings.data.games[0].events[0].state">
        <div class="form-group">
            <button 
                type="button" 
                class="btn largeButton" 
                ng-class="{'btn-success':feature.enabled == true,'btn-danger':feature.enabled == false}" 
                ng-click="feature.child('enabled').set(!feature.enabled);">
                    {{feature.name}}
            </button> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above code works with firebase. All I want to do is set the value from true to false when you click the button and then back again to true if you click it again.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to save the value. The feature is among many features and therefore I can't just search for it from the root element.

To show what Home.OverlaySettings is, have a look at this function:

```
function OverlaySettings(fbURL, $firebase, $q) {
    var fb = {"data":null,"ref":null,"ready":$q.defer()};
    initFB();
    function initFB() {
        fb.ref = new Firebase(fbURL);
        fb.data = $firebase(fb.ref).$asObject();
        fb.data.$loaded(  
            function(data) {
                fb.ready.resolve()
            }
        );
    }
    return function() {
        return fb;
    }
}
```

How can I save the value?

Comment: In this `Home.overlaySettings.ref.feature.child('enabled')` the `feature` is not defined. Remove it and you'll be setting a value in the database. Whether that is the value you want to set is hard to tell from what you shared.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen no it is not. I am trying to save the value of feature.enabled. The problem is that because I am looping features, I don't know which feature it is that I need to save. How do I get the full path of the current feature?

Comment: Ah. I think you're looking for `feature.$id`. So `Home.overlaySettings.ref.child(feature.$id).child('enabled').set(!feature.enabled);` See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38045352/how-to-get-the-key-of-a-firebasearray-object, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997282/angularfire-firebase-geting-a-single-element-from-firebasearray-in-order-t, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28862462/how-to-pull-key-name-from-array-of-objects-in-angularfire

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen that gave me the following error: https://ibb.co/h7GCja

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I also tried printing it out with `{{feature.$id}}` and it just spat out blank.

Comment: You typed `feature.%id`. It should be `feature.$id`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I don't see where I entered %

Comment: The screenshot you posted https://ibb.co/h7GCja has `feature.%id`

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below.

```
Home.overlaySettings.data.games[0].events[0].states[$parent.$index].features[$index].child('enabled').set(!Home.overlaySettings.data.games[0].events[0].states[$parent.$index].features[$index].enabled);
```

Or you can do this job in your controller.